# Crystal Reports reference: File Version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and working with .NET 4.0 C#.

I've downloaded and installed Crystal Reports developer version 13.0.7 (the latest service pack). When I include a reference to one of the DLLs, CrystalDecisions.Shared for example, the version in Properties in my Solution Explorer says 13.0.2000.0 (rather than 13.0.7.1136).
When adding the reference (Reference Manager>>Assemblies>>Extensions) if I click on the name then Visual Studio shows "Version" 13.0.2000.0 and "File Version" 13.0.7.1136.

Does anyone with Crystal Reports experience have ideas about this? I think everything's ok, but the version number is confusing me.

Thank you

Comment: [Relevant](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+2008+%28and+9.1,+XI+R1,+XI+R2%29+-+Version+and+Download+information+for+Service+Packs)

Answer (score 1):

When you installed CR, did you use the msi installer or the exe? It is important to use the exe on the development machine. Also, if you install a new version it is recommended to uninstall the old version.

Comment: I didn't, but I'm definitely using the dll from the latest version. If I right click on it in explorer, details tells me the version is 13.0.7. When I import it as a reference it says File Version 13.0.7, but in the same window (Reference Manager) it says Version 13.0.2 right under that.

Comment: Created thread at SAP (http://scn.sap.com/thread/3457913) where someone notes "The assembly version never changes. E.g.; 13.0.2000.0 is correct. Only the file version changes."
So seems to make sense to me now.